# Product combinations from two or more products

Tags: magento

I am trying to make something like in the following link, using Magento:

http://www.gemvara.com/jewelry/cushion-cut-candace-ring-8mm-gem/cushion-diamond-14k-white-gold-ring-with-diamond/2fgxv

You can see that product main images and all other details change.

Now I tried configuring a bundled product with combination of two or more simple products, but this will create too many products.

Suppose I configure the following:

```
1: 3 products of stones
2: 2 products of ring base
3: Than the total number of products that I will have to create will be 3(stones) + 2(stone base) +6(3*2 bundled product with all possible combinations) = 11 products
```

For more options, this will be to complicated to manage.

How can we use Magento to do this efficiently?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to approach this scenario, depending on whether or not you need to manage inventory stock for each combination.

If you don't need to manage the inventory for each possible combination, then you can use a Simple Product type and use the Custom Options to provide the various options to customers. You can put in price adjustments as well as the SKU that is generated when various selections are shown.

If you do have to manage inventory stock for each combination, then you do have to create — in your example — 6 simple products. Then you can present them using the Configurable product type. In this way if one of the rings is out of stock, the remaining 5 possible combinations are still presented to the customer. Still allowing them to choose a stone and ring base, but not allowing the combination of the one out of stock to be chosen.

So, it really boils down to whether you need to manage stock or not. With Magento CE 1.9.1, there are also more robust swatch image functions that might be helpful with what you're trying achieve, as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want unique images for every permutation, you will need to create each simple product to achieve this.  To make life easier, you could create all the products in a csv and them import with Magmi.

In order to achieve the image option links, check out the latest version of Magento (1.9.1) which now supports option swatches and will load the simple product's base image which would achieve the effect you are after.

Best
Tom

Comment: ok you said to create simple product but how will it work
if i add ring with blue diamond ?? have i to add ring will all possible stone color as ??.

Comment: yes exactly. so your simple products will have an attribute of stones and ring base.  So if you added a blue diamond, you would create 2 products: 1 with stone = blue diamond, ring base = A, and another with stone = blue disamond, ring base = B

Comment: yeah that my main problem for 10 stone with 10 base there will be 100+10+10 products and also lots of images

Comment: if you're not so bothered about having a unique image for each version, or monitoring stock levels per version, you could use 1 simple product and add custom options to it. See the custom option tab on the product edit screen.  Again these can be imported using magmi

Comment: unique images for each combination so that user can see ring with different tops

Comment: Then you will need to set them all up.  magento will comfortably take 10's of thousands of products, provided you have good hosting.  The only downer is the time it will take to setup, but using a csv and a solid naming architecture for your images would help you alot

Comment: but but i want to manage stock of stone and ring base as seprate unit and your process will increase lot of mannula process to maintain stock